# Find shortest walking route that gets me within 100m of all points within polygon

Tags: r, dplyr, gis, r-sf, tibble

I regularly need to devise the shortest walking route that gets me within 100m of all points in a polygon. I normally draw the walking route on a map. But I'm wondering if I can get R to devise the route for me?

In the `poly` can R calculate such a walking route?

```
library(sf); library(tibble); library(dplyr)

lon <- c(-2.28693776739262, -2.28775699708943, -2.28703948292762, -2.29244089927134, -2.29166515832837, -2.30186223039892, -2.30309391144779, -2.3056785372324, -2.30317524849752, -2.29377665148526, -2.28749981389358, -2.28693776739262)

lat <- c(55.8178060589878, 55.8176446224019, 55.8143145424301, 55.8134429653489, 55.8125449362038, 55.8111356982306, 55.8143414682509, 55.8151103263674, 55.8178015760052, 55.8220786729108, 55.8200414980507, 55.8178060589878)

df <- tibble(lon, lat)

poly <- df %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>%
  summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON")
```

Below shows `poly`. I've photoshopped in a possible walking route (red line) but I need R to find the shortest route that gets within 100m of all points within `poly`.

[image]

I'm wondering if an algorithm something like this would work (1) create many lines (2) filter for the line with shortest length and lowest distance to most points.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by walking distance? This polygon looks like it covers a wooded area and some countryside in the Scottish borders. Are you talking about plotting a route using public roads and footpaths? Or are you not restricted to certain paths? In the former case it's basically multi-level Djikstra and the latter it's a slightly more complicated Travelling Salesman Problem.

Comment: I'm after a line inside the polygon that gets within 100m of points inside the polygon. Assume there are no obstacles in the way.

Comment: You could use `st_buffer()` to shrink your polygon by 100m, and calculate the route between the new points. If you Google "R Travelling Salesman Problem" you will find several methods for doing this, some of which scale better than others, but that shouldn't matter in this case.

Comment: I need something different to travelling salesman - don't think I've explained it well. Imagine the inner area of the polygon is filled with say 500 points, I need to devise a line that gets within 100m of each of these 500 points.

Comment: I suspect your approach to create lines and filter them is not feasible as there are too many possible combinations.

Two possible solutions that come to my mind:

1) You could first use an approx. algorithm (clique cover) that finds the minimum number of 100m squares that covers the whole polygon and then apply a TSP algo. to connect the centres of the squares.
2) You could divide the polygon into a grid of rectangles and set up a reinforcement algorithm that navigates through the polygon and collects pos. rewards for unseen areas (in 100m dist) and a negative reward in each period.

Comment: I think this does / can become a traveling salesman problem if you first convert the shape to a collection of 100m radius circles, like this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/374515/fully-cover-polygon-with-circles-of-fixed-radius

Comment: You will have better luck posting this question on the Math stackexchange site.  We are intelligent on this site, but mathematicians are more intelligent with a challenge like this.  Once you know the math behind it, then deal with the programming portion of it.  This deals with computational geometry and ray casting.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon

Comment: Maybe adding the 500 (or 10) points as an example can illustrate the question.